# Magento Product title not showing up?

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, product-view

We have imported our products using the CSV file. Now the products are all displaying, but in the product details page, the page title still shows the main website page title and doesn't have the title related to the product.

It is also not showing the meta title field in the page source as well.

Comment: Have you checked if title data exist in admin product edit page?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there should be `meta_title` field in your csv file for exp:
Just go to `System->Import/Export->Import` and upload a csv file that looks like this:

```
sku, meta_title,meta_description
sku-1,"I am Meta title","Meta Description here"
```

Hope it will help you.